# Run script after user login to kde

Tags: debian, script, kde-4, auto-login

I'm using debian with kde4
I have a script that i need to be executed after a user loggins to kde.
The system is setup to auto-login a user and lock the session. I tried to add the script to kde's autostart but it seams that it's not executed if the auto-login user is set to lock session right away. It only starts after the session is unlocked. How can i make the script run after the aut-login but before the auto-lock?

Comment: I added an answer below, but had another thought:  There is a change the script is catching a term signal with the lock.  Have you tried adding an "&" and the end of the call for the script?  So in the hook you have it would be `script_name.sh &`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to disable the auto-lock by the system and call it after the script is done.  Assuming that you are able or willing to do that:

I don't use KDE, but I think this is the script for KDE 4.x+:

`qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock`

Comment: I just tried your initial solution. Looks like it's working. The downside is that for a couple of seconds (while the desktop loads and stats the screen) the desktop is visible and user can interact with it. I'm waiting for a better solution that works straight with auto-login and auto-lock.

Comment: @AlexLinte I am downloading KDE to try to find a solution for you, assuming no one does in the mean time.

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution so far. Thanks nerdwaller

Comment: Sure thing, I apologize for not getting to test KDE much yet.  Had some school stuff I had to get done.  If I come up with anything, I'll be back in touch.

Answer (score 2):

The desktop-agnostic way to autostart apps in xorg is by placing `*.desktop` launcher files in the following folder:

```
~/.config/autostart
```

Apparently KDE respects the convention and it might work.

The launchers can be copied/symlinked/drag-and-dropped from `/user/share/applications`.

See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74407/74631 for alternative options (*it applies to most modern generic linuces*).

Comment: This only works if i login to desktop. What i want is the script to execute post auto-login, pre auto-lock session.

Comment: @AlexLinte: In that case you probably need to look at the options offered by your login manager: gmd, kdm, lxdm... If you use `gdm` then look at `/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default`. Also look at `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` and/or `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d`.